# When applications deploying using ClickOnce does prerequisites asks for location

Tags: clickonce

When applications deploying using ClickOnce does prerequisites asks for install location?
Once setup is started does it needs any manual inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the prerequiste.  Something like the VS Report Viewer does not.  I think nearly all MS prerequistes install in silent mode.  If you get a package from some other source it would depend on them.